# Tensor Flow Lite Raspberry Pi Installation

Tags: python, tensorflow, raspberry-pi3, tensorflow-lite

I'm looking to install TF Lite on RPi3 for real time image recognition.

I've followed: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/lite/g3doc/rpi.md

All compiled and libtensorflow-lite.a built successfully.

Attempting to run the initial example app:

```
python label_image.py
```

I'm getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): 
   File "label_image.py", line 23, in
      <module> import tensorflow as tf
```

What I'm uncertain about is:

- What I've missed.
- What I need to do to ensure TF uses the lite library and not the full version.
- Lastly - doesn't anyone know what FPS TF lite should achieve on a Pi?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry I did not understand Stack Overflow's rules.
I modified the comment, but please do delete it if reviewers do not like it.

"Tensorflow v1.11.0", which can be introduced by the official pip command, raises problems.

```
undefined symbol: _ZN6tflite12tensor_utils39NeonMatrixBatchVectorMultiplyAccumulateEPKaiiS2_PKfiPfi
```

The pip package appears to be damaged.

The procedure for building Tensorflow Lite is as follows.

1.Execute below.

```
$ sudo apt update;sudo apt upgrade -y
$ sudo apt-get install -y build-essential openjdk-8-jdk pkg-config 
zip g++ zlib1g-dev unzip
```

2.Restart Terminal.

3.Execute below. (Need to run twice)

```
$ sudo apt-get install -y openjdk-8-jdk
```

4.Bazel build.

```
$ cd ~
$ mkdir bazel;cd bazel
$ wget https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/releases/download/0.17.2/bazel-0.17.2-dist.zip
$ unzip bazel-0.17.2-dist.zip
$ nano bazel/scripts/bootstrap/compile.sh

run "${JAVAC}" -classpath "${classpath}" -sourcepath "${sourcepath}" \
-d "${output}/classes" -source "$JAVA_VERSION" -target "$JAVA_VERSION" \
-encoding UTF-8 ${BAZEL_JAVAC_OPTS} "@${paramfile}"
↓
run "${JAVAC}" -classpath "${classpath}" -sourcepath "${sourcepath}" \
-d "${output}/classes" -source "$JAVA_VERSION" -target "$JAVA_VERSION" \
-encoding UTF-8 ${BAZEL_JAVAC_OPTS} "@${paramfile}" -J-Xmx500M

$ sudo bash ./compile.sh
$ sudo cp output/bazel /usr/local/bin
```

5.Prepare for Tensorflow build.

```
$ cd ~
$ sudo pip2 uninstall tensorflow
$ sudo pip3 uninstall tensorflow
$ sudo pip3 install keras_applications==1.0.4 --no-deps
$ sudo pip3 install keras_preprocessing==1.0.2 --no-deps
$ sudo pip3 install h5py==2.8.0
$ git clone -b v1.11.0 https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow.git
$ cd tensorflow
$ git checkout v1.11.0
$ ./tensorflow/contrib/lite/tools/make/download_dependencies.sh
$ ./tensorflow/contrib/lite/tools/make/build_rpi_lib.sh
$ sudo bazel build tensorflow/contrib/lite/toco:toco
```

6-1.Tensorflow's configure. (Python2.x)

```
$ ./configure
WARNING: Running Bazel server needs to be killed, because the startup options are different.
WARNING: --batch mode is deprecated. Please instead explicitly shut down your Bazel server using the command "bazel shutdown".
You have bazel 0.17.2- (@non-git) installed.
Please specify the location of python. [Default is /usr/bin/python]: 
Found possible Python library paths:
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
/usr/local/lib
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
/opt/movidius/caffe/python
Please input the desired Python library path to use.  Default is [/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages]

Do you wish to build TensorFlow with jemalloc as malloc support? [Y/n]: n
No jemalloc as malloc support will be enabled for TensorFlow.

Do you wish to build TensorFlow with Google Cloud Platform support? [Y/n]: n
No Google Cloud Platform support will be enabled for TensorFlow.

Do you wish to build TensorFlow with Hadoop File System support? [Y/n]: n
No Hadoop File System support will be enabled for TensorFlow.

Do you wish to build TensorFlow with Amazon AWS Platform support? [Y/n]: n
No Amazon AWS Platform support will be enabled for TensorFlow.

Do you wish to build TensorFlow with Apache Kafka Platform support? [Y/n]: n
No Apache Kafka Platform support will be enabled for TensorFlow.

Do you wish to build TensorFlow with XLA JIT support? [y/N]: n
No XLA JIT support will be enabled for TensorFlow.

Do you wish to build TensorFlow with GDR support? [y/N]: n
No GDR support will be enabled for TensorFlow.

Do you wish to build TensorFlow with VERBS support? [y/N]: n
No VERBS support will be enabled for TensorFlow.

Do you wish to build TensorFlow with nGraph support? [y/N]: n
No nGraph support will be enabled for TensorFlow.

Do you wish to build TensorFlow with OpenCL SYCL support? [y/N]: n
No OpenCL SYCL support will be enabled for TensorFlow.

Do you wish to build TensorFlow with CUDA support? [y/N]: n
No CUDA support will be enabled for TensorFlow.

Do you wish to download a fresh release of clang? (Experimental) [y/N]: n
Clang will not be downloaded.

Do you wish to build TensorFlow with MPI support? [y/N]: n
No MPI support will be enabled for TensorFlow.

Please specify optimization flags to use during compilation when bazel option "--config=opt" is specified [Default is -march=native]: 


Would you like to interactively configure ./WORKSPACE for Android builds? [y/N]: n
Not configuring the WORKSPACE for Android builds.

Preconfigured Bazel build configs. You can use any of the below by adding "--config=<>" to your build command. See tools/bazel.rc for more details.
--config=mkl            # Build with MKL support.
--config=monolithic     # Config for mostly static monolithic build.
Configuration finished
```

6-2.Tensorflow's configure. (Python3.x)

```
Please specify the location of python. [Default is /usr/bin/python]: /usr/bin/python3


Found possible Python library paths:
  /usr/local/lib
  /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages
  /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages
Please input the desired Python library path to use.  Default is [/usr/local/lib] /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages
```

7.Tensorflow's build.

```
$ sudo bazel build --config opt --local_resources 1024.0,0.5,0.5 \
--copt=-mfpu=neon-vfpv4 \
--copt=-ftree-vectorize \
--copt=-funsafe-math-optimizations \
--copt=-ftree-loop-vectorize \
--copt=-fomit-frame-pointer \
--copt=-DRASPBERRY_PI \
--host_copt=-DRASPBERRY_PI \
//tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package
```

8.Tensorflow's install.

```
$ sudo ./bazel-bin/tensorflow/tools/pip_package/build_pip_package /tmp/tensorflow_pkg
$ sudo pip2 install /tmp/tensorflow_pkg/tensorflow-1.11.0-cp27-cp27mu-linux_armv7l.whl
Or
$ sudo pip3 install /tmp/tensorflow_pkg/tensorflow-1.11.0-cp35-cp35m-linux_armv7l.whl
```

9.【Required】 Restart the terminal.

10.Execute below.

```
$ sudo apt install -y python-scipy python3-scipy
$ sudo apt remove openjdk-8-*
$ sudo apt purge openjdk-8-*
```

If done so far the problem should have been solved.
However, it takes 27 hours in total.
If you do not wait for 27 hours, you can use cross build or drastically reduce waiting time using the proposed wheel file.

Pre-build Tensorflow binary(wheel) is below.
https://github.com/PINTO0309/Tensorflow-bin

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/21190706)

Comment: @Mark Rotteveel
Thank you for pointing out.
I reviewed the sentence of the answer.
Regarding Tensorflow's official issue, there was a report that my solution could be used and the problem was solved.
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/23082

Answer (score 0):

> What I've missed.

To install Tensorflow on Raspberry Pi, You can use official pip package

```
pip install tensorflow
```

For more detail visit official documentation page -

```
https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip
```

Or if you want Cross compiled package, you can follow this official documentation page -

```
https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source_rpi
```

> What I need to do to ensure TF uses the lite library and not the full version.

You just need a trained model and convert it to TFLite model. For complete detail you can follow this tutorial -

```
https://medium.com/tensorflow/training-and-serving-a-realtime-mobile-object-detector-in-30-minutes-with-cloud-tpus-b78971cf1193
```

> Lastly - doesn't anyone know what FPS TF lite should achieve on a Pi?

I am currently working on it, but as there is some issue in tensorflow's current official build for Raspberry pi (https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/23082), I am not able to calculate the performance on Pi.

Answer (score 0):

To follow Ishita Shah's review, I am posting here my steps to build/run the 2 kick-off apps for TfLite running on Raspberry Pi 3 :-)

1, Follow https://www.raspberrypi.org/learning/software-guide/quickstart/, to install Raspbian onto a Raspberry Pi 3 board.

`#sudo apt install build-essential`
Follow https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/contrib/pi_examples to install camera. 
Verify if the camera works or not:

`#raspistill -v`

2, git clone -b r1.12 https://github.com/huaxiaozhong1/tensorflow.git. (The best, this is done within the latest docker container of Ubuntu 18.04).
It will clone 6 static libraries into /tensorflow/tensorflow/contrib/lite/examples/camera/libs:
libjpeg.a librt.a libv4l1.a libv4l2.a libv4l2rds.a libv4lconvert.a.
Actually they are from Pi environment prepared at step 1:

3, In the container of host:

`#apt update`

`#apt upgrade`

`#apt install crossbuild-essential-armhf`

`#cd /tensorflow`

`#./tensorflow/contrib/lite/tools/make/download_dependencies.sh`

`#apt install -y libjpeg-dev`

`#apt install libv4l-dev`

`#./tensorflow/contrib/lite/tools/make/build_rpi_lib.sh`

Now, you could find ./tensorflow/contrib/lite/tools/make/gen/rpi_armv7l/lib/libtensorflow-lite.a, /tensorflow/tensorflow/contrib/lite/tools/make/gen/rpi_armv7l/bin/label_image and /tensorflow/tensorflow/contrib/lite/tools/make/gen/rpi_armv7l/bin/camera.

4, Copy label_image and camera, the Linux executables, to Raspeberry board. 
Copy grace_hopper.bmp from /tensorflow/tensorflow/contrib/lite/examples/label_image/testdata of host’s container to the board.
Copy labels.txt from /tensorflow/tensorflow/contrib/lite/java/ovic/src/testdata of host’s container to the board.
Download Mobilenet_v2_1.0_224_quant.tflite from https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/lite/g3doc/models.md to the board.
The 3 data files and 2 Linux executables should be inside the same folder.

5, Run the 2 apps one by one.

Note: the base branch that I added the 2 apps into is r1.12. Now TfLite has been announced to move out of contrib. But when I ran build_rpi_lib.sh in the latest tensorflow/tensorflow:nightly-devel, it didn’t get success. So, may I submit the pull-request based at r1.12 right now? I could add the same feature on r1.13+ as soon as it succeeds in building libtensorflow-lite.a.